# Linkedin Groups not getting in android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

Am trying to get the groups in my linkedin, Am using this call http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships?count=10&start=10&format=json but when i try to call this url its getting error message "Access to group-memberships denied".

Here is my code:

```
  String message="";
  Token requestToken;
   service = new ServiceBuilder()
   .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
  .apiKey("XXXXXXXXXX") 
 .apiSecret("XXXXXXXXXX")
 .build();

  requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

String url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships?count=10&  start=10&format=json";
     OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, url);

      request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      service.signRequest(linkrdInToken, request);


     Response response = request.send();
```

Comment: have you taken the "rw_groups" and "r_fullprofile" permission ?

Comment: thank u for ur time, am using both permissions still getting the issue.